# How long is homemade spiced apple cider good for in a sealed Mason canning jar?

Tags: boiling, canning, fresh

I bring the cider to a boil and simmer the spices for 15 minutes. Immediately after, I pour the cider into canning Mason glass jars with the lids that have the button. How long should I expect the cider to be good for unopened?

Comment: Your title says sealed, but if you're not processing it after filling, I don't think you can really guarantee that they're sealed. Are you willing to perhaps change your process if your goal is to get it to last?

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely open to that. I would be curious what the longevity would be for both processes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you follow the usual procedere of cleaning and boiling ("sterilizing"<sup>1</sup>) the jars, filling the hot cider in hot jars and closing immediately, you *should be fine* for a few weeks. Or not, there is always a slight risk of the jars not sealing properly and your cider not being acidic enough.

But:
Processing the jars as you would for other canning and *repeating* the processing after a day or two should get you on the super-safe side (including eliminating the very, very slim botulism risk from your spices).

*This is probably overkill, even a standard waterbath canning should leave you with a cider that stays good for a year or more.*

Just remove the rings after the jars have cooled well, so that any faulty seal becomes obvious right away.